# Trying to draw multiple level scene in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

this is my jsfiddle : [jsfiddle.net/V8eKp/5/show](http://jsfiddle.net/V8eKp/4/show/)

```
       // START -- MOVE CAMERA
            var p = new b2Vec2();
            p = (ball.body.GetWorldCenter().x) * physics.scale;
            pos.push(p);
            var length = pos.length;

            var s = (pos[length - 1] - pos[length - 2]); //in pixels

            if ((halfwidth < (dw - p)) && (p > halfwidth)) {
                ctx.translate(-s, 0);
            }
```

I followed the code in here : http://www.codingowl.com/readblog.php?blogid=128

1. the rendering of the ball is acting weirdly and slow

   i saw this example : http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/05/04/following-a-body-with-the-camera-in-box2d-the-smart-way/ but i didn't figure out how he do it he used 3 variables `stage,x,y` wish are undefined in the code he wrote.
   and check out this demo by Impactjs and look how the camera move with the player movement i need this functionality : http://impactjs.com/demos/physics/

please can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

As long as `ball.body.GetPosition().x > 48`, `this.current` will start incrementing on each update, right? But your `draw()` only handles 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: ok i know that but the incrementing is going so fast for example if the ball reached the second scene `this.current` should be `2` but it's not it keeps incrementing

Comment: What prevents `this.current` from incrementing further? Where is the ball position reset to avoid the first `if` from firing again and again?

Comment: if you see this line `if (ball.body.GetPosition().x > 48) {
                        // ball.body.SetPosition(new b2Vec2(2, 25));`
when i un-comment it the drawing of the scene work fine but problem number 2 occurred if i want to draw a rectangle that is common between two different scene!!!

Comment: would u tell me how can i fix this problem ? please

Comment: I believe you should not shift the ball and the scene but rather shift the offset of the scene when painted in the canvas, if that is possible with the library.

Comment: what do you mean ? by shifting the offset ?

Comment: I mean that instead of moving all the objects in your world to (0, 0), you potentially can tell the rendering subsystem to render all objects shifted by a certain amount (so that, say, an object at (20, 0) will be rendered at (0, 0), and the one at (50, 5) at (30, 5)).

Comment: can u please provide an example or a link wish can explain how this can be done ? because this is the first time i actually know that this can happened

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51186/discussion-between-sora-and-alexander-pavlov)

Answer (score 0):

Got a (kind of) working fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4Mv5/

You already got most of it right, just need a bit of work on the scene change logic.

My logic is, whenever the scene change, remove everything, manually shift the ball back or forward, and completely redraw the new scene.
As we are manually shifting the ball, the canvas does not need to be translated.

Draw and loop code: (Simplified)

```
            draw: function () {
                this.clear();
                new Body(physics, { name: "Ground" });
                ball = new Body(physics, { shape: "circle", x: ballx, y: bally, radius: 0.5 });
                switch ( this.current ) {
                case 0: // First scene
                    new Body(physics, { name: "Scene0Wall" });
                    new Body(physics, { name: "Scene0bricks0" });
                    new Body(physics, { name: "Scene0bricks1" });
                    break;

                case 1: // Second scene
                    new Body(physics, { name: "Scene1bricks0" });
                    break;

                case 2: // Third scene
                    new Body(physics, { name: "Scene2bricks0" });
                    break;
                }
            },
            update: function () {
                ballx = ball.body.GetPosition().x;
                bally = ball.body.GetPosition().y;
                if ( ballx > scene_width ) {
                    ++this.current;
                    ballx -= scene_width;
                    this.draw();
                }
                if ( ballx < 0 && this.current > 0) {
                    --this.current;
                    ballx += scene_width;
                    this.draw();
                }
            },
```

This is also easier on scene layout since each scene's origin is [0,0].

I'm only preserving the balls' position, not its state and velocity, which you should implement.  The scene layout (and scene cut off point) should also be adjusted to make sure the ball can continue its journey instead of getting stuck in a block.

Comment: but this is not my question... u surely didn't read my question or the code i posted

Comment: @Sora I'm sorry I misunderstood. I based it on your second fiddle in the comment, trying to guess what you want.  Yes I read that you want the camera move with player.  May I ask has the issue been resolved?

Comment: no i couldn't resolve the problem yet :/ did you see the jsfiddle ? could u managed to see how the whole scene start to shake ?

Comment: @Sora Hmm. When I tried the original fiddle (V8eKp/4), I can't get the ball jump, but it's otherwise smooth (no shaking) and the camera follow the ball.

Comment: really ? it is shaking in my browser due to the slow translation of the scene

Comment: the camera follow the ball but when i reach the end of the scene and the camera start moving u can see that a slower movement occur and yes the jumping isn't done yet

Comment: @Sora Ok, I'll try again in a few hours with a slower pc and profile it to see what I can find.

Comment: great i am waiting for your Edit bcs i still can't find whats wrong with this behavior

Comment: i updated my fiddle to : http://jsfiddle.net/V8eKp/5/show/ the jumping is set . try to move the ball and leave it you can see in some point the ball start to shake wish make the whole scene slow